# Where can I find information on the DC-9's turn radius in flight?

Tags: aircraft-performance, dc-9-family

Does anyone know where I can find information on a DC-9-30's turn radius at various altitudes and airspeeds?  I've tried Googling it, but all I've found is information about its turn radius *while taxiing*.

Answer (score 4):

No different from any other jet.  Use this turn radius calculator http://www.csgnetwork.com/aircraftturninfocalc.html

Comment: Unfortunately, "[t]his calculator DOES NOT take into consideration wind speed or direction, temperature, air density or aircraft performance and assumes LEVEL flight and turns", and I kinda need to be able to take those factors into account (it's for a short story I'm thinking of writing, and I need it to be as realistic as possible).

Comment: @Sean, if you want to take these things into account, you have to specify them. Very, very precisely. And also specify what you actually mean by turn radius, because once wind is involved, you can be using wind-relative or ground-relative frame of reference and the results will obviously be different in each (and the turn will not really be a circle in the ground one).

Comment: @Sean, I believe you can account for density by simply giving all the speeds as TAS valid for the desired density altitude.

Comment: @JanHudec: The specific scenario I have in mind is DC-9-32, ground-relative turn radius, 10-knot wind, temperature 85F, altitude 10,800' AMSL, 260 KIAS.

Comment: @Sean As a constant wind from one direction distorts the turn, speaking of ground-related turn radius doesn’t make much sense in practice, I‘d say - it constantly changes throughout the turn. If you specify wind direction and speed (assuming constant wind) as well as bank angle used for the turn and aircraft heading before and after the turn, one can model the ground track, if that helps?

Comment: @CptReynolds: Yes, that'll do (wind from 115 degrees at 10 knots).

Comment: @Sean Well, as I said, you’d need to specify wind direction, wind speed, aircraft heading before and after the turn, and the bank angle you‘d like to use (normally in airliners up to about 25° depending on the situation), and whether you‘d like a constant bank angle or something else (e.g. flying the turn to intercept a given course from/to a navigation aid) etc. If you want high detail, you need to specify at a detailed level, please. If you decide that, in fact, that level of detail isn’t required for the story after all, then anything that turn radius calculator can generate will be fine.